# Proof varification: coset of the subgroup $H\cap K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a group $G$. Prove that the intersection $xH\cap yK$ of two cosets of $H$ and $K$ is either empty or else is a coset of the subgroup $H\cap K$.

My thought is $xH\cap yK=\{xh: h\in H\}\cap\{yk:k\in K\}$. If $x\neq y$ then the intersection is $\{1\}$. If $x=y$ then $xH\cap xK=x(H\cap K)$ which is a coset of $H\cap K$.

But my argument is not right, I think. Since $x\neq y$ then $xh=yk$ where $h\in H$ and $k\in K$ then $x=ykh^{-1}$. Then the only condition we need is $kh^{-1}\neq 1\Rightarrow k\neq h$. What should I do next?

Comment: Why do you say that $x\neq y\Longrightarrow$ the intersection is $\{1\}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I understood I am wrong (I wrote that too) but no idea what to do.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos one point I found that $y=1$ and $K=xH$ my argument $x\neq y\Longrightarrow$ the intersection is $\{1\}$ is not right proves. But that does not solve the problem anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z\in xH$ then $xH=zH$. If $z\in yK$ then $yK=zK$. So if
$z\in xH\cap yK$ then $xH=zH$ and $yK=zK$. Then $xH\cap yK=zH\cap zK\ldots$.

Comment: Okayyyy! Just missed that point! Thank a lot!